# Template with variables

Tags: angular, text-editor

I would like to personalize an email with different variables, that is, select a word and add a certain character such as: $, {}, [] to know that it is a variable, something like this: {name} I would like to know if there is any plugin for Angular 14+ that could help me in this case.
I attach an example that I saw on www.courier...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can play with regExpr, e.g.

```
data={'one':'Dolly','two':'a sheep'}
message="Hello {one} I'm {two}"

message2=this.parseMessage(message)

parseMessage(message:string){
  Object.keys(this.data).forEach(key=>{
    const regexp=new RegExp('\\{'+key+'\\}','gi')
    message=message.replace(regexp,this.data[key])
  })
  return message
}
```